# How to have timestamp as the only delimiter in Grok Logstash?

Tags: grok, logstash-grok

I have a log entry like the following:-

```
2014-10-13 16:42:46,946 [1] DEBUG SolaceManager - Creating Solace session: Host=abc, 
VPN=xyz, User=indiana, ConnectRetries=-1, SendBlocking=True
```

To parse it using grok, I have used the following pattern in logstash:-

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Logdate} \[%{NUMBER:ThreadId}\] %{WORD:LogLevel} ?%{GREEDYDATA:data}"
```

The above code does not work and I get the following messages:-

```
1) @message= 2014-10-13 16:42:46,946 [1] DEBUG SolaceManager - Creating Solace session:
2) @message= Host=abc,
3) @message= User=indiana,
4) @message= ConnectRetries=-1,
5) @message= SendBlocking=True
```

This is not expected, I require a single message as :-

```
@message = 2014-10-13 16:42:46,946 [1] DEBUG SolaceManager - Creating Solace session: Host=abc, 
VPN=xyz, User=indiana, ConnectRetries=-1, SendBlocking=True
```

In other words, is there a way to make sure that only timestamp acts as delimitter?

Comment: can you provide your logstash config?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a mutate after the grok is matched like

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Logdate} \[%{NUMBER:ThreadId}\] %{WORD:LogLevel} ?%{GREEDYDATA:data}"
    }
}

mutate {
        replace      => [ "@message", "%{message}" ]
        remove_field => [ "message" ]
}
```

this should add the complete message in the @message field